# building array of custom objects causes nullpointerexception

Tags: android, arrays, custom-object

Im declaring from a big list of custom, multiple level, objects (here called venueCounter) a simple array of custom objects, with just the information needed for filling a list. I do this because its easier to sort my list and create sections in my list.

But when i try it i get a nullpointerexception. I think that is very weird, because when i tried to fill a stringArray it worked fine. Here is my code that fails:

```
 ListData ld[]= new ListData[venueCounter.size()];
     int selectedPic;
     JJsonResponse e;
     for(int i=0;i < venueCounter.size() ;i++){
         selectedPic = 0;
         e = venueCounter.get(i);
         ld[i]= null;//           data in listdata object   
         ld[i].name=e.venue.name;
         ld[i].tip_nl=e.venue.tip;
         ld[i].tip_en=e.venue.tip_en;
         ld[i].venueID=e.venue.id;
         // foto uitkiezien
         if (e.venue.venue_photos.isEmpty() == false){ // there is a picture
            for(int j=0; j < e.venue.venue_photos.size() ;j++){ // use user selected picture
                 if(e.venue.venue_photos.get(j).selected == true){ 
                     selectedPic = j;
                 }
                ld[i].photoUrl=e.venue.venue_photos.get(selectedPic).medium;
             }
         }else
             {
             ld[i].photoUrl="url for when there is no url";
           }

         Log.i("url nr. " + String.valueOf(i), ld[i].photoUrl);
     }
```

and the line with the error is:

```
ld[i].name=e.venue.name;
```

But the strange thing is, that when i declare a string array and fill it just the same:

```
String name[]=new String[venueCounter.size()];
```

and further in the code

```
name[i]=e.venue.name;
```

everything just works fine! But i want this array of listdata, so i can put it in my adapter and just work with it. 
Does anyone knows why my code fails and what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem here is the line with

```
 ld[i]= null;
```

If you make it null it wont be able to save any data. You should do a new ListData()... instead of the null.

It works with Strings because whenever you make a string equal to another, java creates the new object and so on.

Hope I have explained it correctly.

Comment: You are right! Thank you. I thought that i would create a new (empty) field in my array, and than fill it up in the next lines.